# Attempt to index global 'head' (a nil value) love2d

Tags: lua, love2d

I am experimenting with lua through a simple snake game, but I keep getting this error that I am stuck on.

code:

```
function love.load()

    width, height = love.window.getDimensions()
    start= {x= width/2, y = height/2}

    snake = {}
    snake.dir = 0
    snake.speed = 300
    snake.body  = {}


    for i = 0, 5, 1 do
        table.insert(snake.body,{x=start.x,y=start.y + i })
    end

end

function love.keypressed(key)

    if key == "left" and snake.dir ~= 1 then 
        snake.dir = 0
    end
    if key == "right" and snake.dir ~= 0 then
        snake.dir = 1
    end 
    if key == "up" and snake.dir ~= 3 then
        snake.dir = 2
    end
    if key == "down" and snake.dir ~= 2 then
        snake.dir = 3
    end

end 

function love.update(dt)

    head = snake.body[0]

    if snake.dir == 0 then
        head = {head.x - snake.speed*dt, head.y}
    end

    if snake.dir == 1 then
        head = {head.x + snake.speed*dt, head.y}
    end

    if snake.dir == 2 then
        head = {head.x, head.y - snake.speed*dt}
    end

    if snake.dir == 3 then
        head = {head.x, head.y + snake.speed*dt}
    end 

    table.insert(snake.body,0,head)
    table.remove(snake.body,#snake.body)

end

function love.draw()


end
```

The error is in function update.

Also, how would i iterate through each snake part? Like what is the foreach equivalent in lua? Thanks for any help

Comment: Lua table indices are 1-based.  Change min index from 0 to 1 in these lines: `for i = 0, 5, 1 do`, `head = snake.body[0]` and `table.insert(snake.body,0,head)`

Comment: Also change `head = {head.x - snake.speed*dt, head.y}` to `head = {x = head.x - snake.speed*dt, y = head.y}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables (arrays) in Lua are 1-indexed not 0-indexed. So the first item in the array should be 1 not 0.

When defining your snake body, start at 1 not 0:

```
for i = 1, 5 do
    table.insert(snake.body,{x=start.x,y=start.y + i })
end
```

And then in your update handler:

```
head = snake.body[1]
```

To iterate through an array you can use ipairs for numeric indices or pairs for named keys: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ForTutorial

For example, assuming `snake.body` is a numerically referenced list, you could do:

```
for key, value in ipairs(snake.body) do
   ...
end
```

To iterate everything on `snake` you could do:

```
for key, value in pairs(snake) do
   ...
end
```

Also, for your `keypressed` handler, would it not be cleaner to use a lookup table?

```
local keyToDir = { left = 0, right = 1, up = 2, down = 3 }

function love.keypressed(key)
   local dir = keyToDir[key];
   if dir then snake.dir = dir end;
end
```